# Ordering the matching of URLs in the Retour Plugin

Tags: plugin-retour

I have a client who has a legacy matching pattern of "/news(.*)" which catches all the news pages that have been de-activated and redirects them to a landing news page.  The issues that one particular news page got so much traffic, they decided to make it a main page on the site.  So they want to redirect the traffic from /news/popular-article/ to /site/new-popular-page.  The trouble is... retour catches the now deactivated page in the "/news(.*)" redirect - I want it to catch specifically "/news/popular-article/"

How do I sequence the testing of regexes in Retour / prioritise some matches over others?

Answer (score 1):

So the only work around I've found here is to delete the "/news(.)" entry and re-add it, and that seems to put it at the end of the matching list.

Hope there is a more elegant solution here.